# Find and replace text in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a html file with href hyperlinks to certain files. I want to find all the href links in this file and replace the links with the absolute paths to the file.

```
<BR><CENTER><TABLE BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=0 NOSAVE><TR ALIGN=CENTER NOSAVE><TD COLSPAN="4" NOSAVE><CENTER><B>Summary Table</B></CENTER><TR><TD>Testname</TD><TD>Status</TD><TD>Link to HTML</TD><TD>Utility</TD></TR><TR><TD>test1</TD><TD>FAIL</TD><TD><A HREF= abc.html>HTML_report</a></BR></TD><TD>run</TD></TR><TR><TD>31Jan2017_03h12m52s</TD><TD>FAIL</TD><TD><A HREF=def.html>HTML_report</a></BR></TD><TD>run_2</TD></TR></TABLE></CENTER><BR>
```

After replacing, this should look like -

```
<BR><CENTER><TABLE BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=0 NOSAVE><TR ALIGN=CENTER NOSAVE><TD COLSPAN="4" NOSAVE><CENTER><B>Summary Table</B></CENTER><TR><TD>Testname</TD><TD>Status</TD><TD>Link to HTML</TD><TD>Utility</TD></TR><TR><TD>test1</TD><TD>FAIL</TD><TD><a href=common?htmlview=1&file="absolute_path to abc.html">HTML_report</a></BR></TD><TD>run</TD></TR><TR><TD>31Jan2017_03h12m52s</TD><TD>FAIL</TD><TD><a href=common?htmlview=1&file="absolute_path to def.html">HTML_report</a></BR></TD><TD>run_2</TD></TR></TABLE></CENTER><BR>
```

I am reading the html file line by line, so a single line can have more than one occurrence of a href.
I have tried using re.sub to find and place -

```
re.sub(r'\sA\sHREF\s','a href=common?htmlview=1&file=<path>',line)
```

Comment: Why are you parsing HTML with regex?

Comment: One doesn't simply parses html with regex [for these reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). You may use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: ... did you have a question?

Comment: The result you want is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use regex to manipulate html, using lib such as [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<BR><CENTER><TABLE BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=0 NOSAVE><TR ALIGN=CENTER NOSAVE><TD COLSPAN="4" NOSAVE><CENTER><B>Summary Table</B></CENTER><TR><TD>Testname</TD><TD>Status</TD><TD>Link to HTML
</TD><TD>Utility</TD></TR><TR><TD>test1</TD><TD>FAIL</TD><TD><A HREF= abc.html>HTML_report</a></BR></TD><TD>run</TD></TR><TR><TD>31Jan2017_03h12m52s</TD><TD>FAIL</TD><TD><A HREF=def.html>HTML_report</a></BR></TD
><TD>run_2</TD></TR></TABLE></CENTER><BR>')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    link['href'] = 'fix the absolute path here %s' % (link.get('href'),)

print soup.prettify()
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @Toto Normally I'd agree but I can't say "this is not an attempt to answer the question" in this case because there is no question.

Comment: @melpomene: Right, but no question ==> no answer.